# libtiff4 under Ubuntu14.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, libtiff

With the release of Ubuntu14.04, Ubuntu is using `libtiff5` and not `libtiff4` any more. However some programs/libraries etc are still using `libtiff4` and therefore do not work under 14.04 any longer. My question now, is there any way to install `libtiff4` (not just `libtiff4-dev`) under Ubuntu14.04?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so by downloading the .deb file from the Ubuntu repo web page: [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/libtiff4).

Simply select your architecture, select a mirror from the list, and under "Open with" select "Ubuntu Software Center"

Hope this works!

*It should be noted, however, that there are definite stability and security issues with using software that is no longer being maintained.*